# Does canonical+6wind vswitch support vlan transparent?

Tags: canonical

We are planning to migrate to canonical openstack with 6wind vswitch. Does anyone know this platform support vlan transparency?

Answer (score 0):

I made a lab deployment of their solution with Juju and tried both VXLAN and VLAN. Both are supported and were very easy to deploy. I did try OVS-DPDK too, but it was not good enough for my needs. I could even use brctl and tcpdump with 6wind vswitch...

We plan to get it in production soon.